# Bug/Error Pycharm shows me an error but django doesnt while I am importing an app

Tags: django, pycharm

I am learning Djnago with the IDE Pycharm all its great but when i write  the following command on Pycharm, it shows me an error:
from app import views, it means import all the views from my app but Pycharm shows me an error that says :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rubM.png
And also I included my app in settings.py, but the worst part(I think) its when I run python manager.py runserver it doesn show me any error in my app 
Does anyone knows if its a bug, my IDE is wrong or something else? 
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an error per se, which is why server runs fine; Pycharm just can't find a reference to your app for some reason. Perhaps you should just add it to the ignored references or something. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/resolving-references.html

Also, you should check where this is coming from 'misitio.misitio.urls.biblioteca'

Answer (score 0):

This is a configuration issue of pycharm. First you need to make sure that you are pointing to the correct python executable (inside a virtualenv if you use one). Then I suggest you enable the django project support from settings / languages and frameworks / django and make sure the paths to your project are correct.